# What are good money making ideas for teenagers in the city?

Tags: self-employment, new-york

we are 3 teens in the city looking for ideas to make money. We are minors enrolled in a good school. We are interested in filling our free time but make money during it.

Here are some of our ideas

-Reselling items (books, tech, etc.)

-Tutoring/Babysitting (below 9th grade curriculum, some music)

-Selling food (make/buy)

-Contests/Scholarships (Hackathons, Environmental, Community Service, etc.)

-Straight up labour (shovel snow during winter, help moving, etc)

​

Comment: I am voting to close this question as too broad. There are just too many ways to create an income, and which one is the most lucrative / least hard way for you depends on you, your skills, your resources and your personal preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you look into garage sales, flea markets flipping items online on Facebook marketplace and/or eBay.

Its a relatively low-entry barrier field that you can go in with little to no money for the short term and it also fits your lifestyle as a school-going teenager since it requires relatively low effort timewise and enables flexible work hours, but can also scale well enough should you decide to go deeper into it.

Plenty of material on getting started online as well.

p.s. since it was mentioned, things like hackathons if you re tech inclined may not have an immediate economic impact in your life but if you re interested in the field, it can go a long way as an investment to your future.